# Gettin error bjSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo") in classical ASP in IIS7.0

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, ldap

I'm getting undefined object CreateObject("ADSystemInfo") when I embed the code in classical asp that is hosted in IIS7.0 on Windows Server 2008. When I excute the same code on that server using VBscript it is working fine. Could  some one help me. I need to know if I need to make any server settings changes

```
Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
strUserDN = objSysInfo.UserName
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strUserDN)
arrGroups = objUser.memberOf
```

Comment: I've added the code, I'm getting following error "Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01f4' 

Variable is undefined: 'ADSysInfo'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because what you wrote about is actually VBScript, and not Classic ASP.

You can run this from the cmd window and it should work fine.  But to convert it to ASP, you have to do a couple things.

Surround your code with

```
<%

... code here

%>
```

And then change every instance of `CreateObject` to `Server.CreateObject`

Your code would look like this:

```
<%
 Set objSysInfo = Server.CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
 strUserDN = objSysInfo.UserName
 Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strUserDN)
 arrGroups = objUser.memberOf
%>
```

Finally, make sure that the IIS webserver is running as a [user that has the correct permissions.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/278836)

Comment: @Mike: Thanks for the reply. Sorry I'm slightly confused with the your second part. Do this means we need to send the user's id and pwd ( seerver id /pwd) to LDAP or is there any specific setting we need to do in IIS . I'm using IIS 7.0.

Comment: @SRT_KP I updated the answer to show how the code should look.

Comment: @Mike: Thank you. My ASP code is exactly same. Still I'm getting error Could you please expian other part regarding "permissions" we need to have?

Comment: @ Michael Pryor Could you please help by letting me know what necessary changes I need to do in IIS